# Android background image not showing

Tags: android, background

I'm currently working on a Android project, which requires me to put an image as background for some activities. I'm using Android Studio to develop the app, and have tested the app on multiple devices.

At first I had put the background image in the drawable folder. This resulted in a mayor framerate drop because of rescaling the image. After this I had put the image in the drawable-nodpi folder.
I tested the app on a Motorola Moto G (Android L), Nexus 5 (Android L) and Nexus 9 (Android L) and everything worked well.

To make sure the app was working for multiple devices, I started a mdpi Jellybean emulator via Android Studio. Suprisingly, the background was only loaded into 2/4 activities (all are using the same resource). After some research I decided to pre-scale the background and place it in the drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi folders etc. Tested again and now the the background was only not showing up on 1 activity. I decided to test on multiple devices with older api's. I found that my app had this problem with every device with a api below Android L.

Can somebody please explain to me how this is possible, as all the activities are using the same resource?

Kind regards,

Jur

Student ICT Software development

EDIT
I added the background to the Drawable folder.

Source code of activity that loads the background

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="nl.beachbash.beachbash.InfoListActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:backgroundTint="#32dd6800"
android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
android:id="@+id/background">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listViewInfo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:divider="#FFFFFF" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Source code of activity that doesn't load the background

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="nl.beachbash.beachbash.FloorPlanActivity"
android:backgroundTint="#32dd6800"
android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
android:background="@drawable/background">

<nl.beachbash.customUI.TouchImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Floorplan" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post your implementation so far... have you tried putting those resource files in the `drawable` folder?

Comment: No matter which way you swing it, using a rasterized image for the background of your activity is going to be expensive from both a computation and memory perspective.

That said, it shouldn't be "flaky" across activities. How are you setting the background? Are you using the theme attribute `android:windowBackground` or are you setting it as the background of your root view in each Activity?

Comment: I have added the source code of the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem myself.

I tried making a new activity, put in the exact same code, build the exact same interface and added the background the same way as above, but this time it apparently worked.
No idea why...

Comment: A common reason for this is memory. Even though it is working, I highly suggestion resizing the image down, and then using compression algorithms on the image to also reduce disk size. Cheers!